# Get custom HTML attribute of dragged and dropped element in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm building a card game where every card (every div with class *card*) is draggable. The cards can be dropped onto all the other cards by default, but I'm using the [accept option](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) to calculate if the card shoule be accepted or reverted after it has been dropped. A card should only be droppable onto another card which value is 1 higher than the dragged card. 7's can only be dropped on 8's for example. The card's values (1-13) are stored in the custom attribute `data-value`.

This means that when a card is dropped onto another, I need to know if the dragged card's `data-value` is one less than the `data-value` of the card it's dropped onto. How can I access these two `data-value`'s?

```
$(".card").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

$(".card").droppable({

  accept: function(d) {

    // Here I want to access the custom HTML attribute "data-value" of both dragged card and droppable card

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I suspect there's another, simpler solution.

```
    $(".card").droppable({     

        accept: function(d) {

            if ($(d[0]).data("value") == $(this).data("value") -1) {

                return true;

            }

        }

    });
```